# RESTful GET URL end with .0

Tags: java, restful-url

I have a GET endpoint with the URL is api/v1/v4network/{address}.
When I try with api/v1/v4network/1.1.1.0, I only get 1.1.1 value of address instead of 1.1.1.0. I also use ASCII for address, but it met the same issue.

Thanks all!

Comment: What are you using to handle this request in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix my problem.

Only using PathVariable with RegEx

I have used

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{address:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and it working correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Try URL Encoding the Ip Address. I think your REST framework considers the last `.` and the rest as extension. `.` is `%2E` when URL Encoded.

```
1%2E1%2E1%2E0
```

Comment: I have try with 1%2E1%2E1%2E0, but I still received 1.1.1